# .net Core 5 _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync error: Username 'XXXX' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, c#-5.0

I have the following code in .Net 5.0 using Identity:

```
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles.ToArray());
```

`UserID` is a valid UserID and returns a valid `user`
`roles` is correctly populated with the roles belonging to the `user`
`RemoveFromRolesAsync` fails with the following error:

```
Username 'xxx' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added

```
options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+/\"
```

to

```
IdentityHostingStartup.cs
```

**Note:** it seems the allowed characters match is case sensitive ...